# CQL expecting set null error

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to export the cassandra data to file using CQL . But i am getting '**expecting set null**' error. My keyspace name and column family name are same.[image]

Cassandra version : 1.1.2

Actually i need to export cassandra data to csv or any format. But i tried most of the export commands. But getting the same error. keyspace name and column family name are same is that an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is upgrade to 1.1.8.  If that still doesn't work, file a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA.